# When deploying to github pages, fetch is working from my pc but not from my smarphone

Tags: javascript, post, get, fetch, backend

I am trying to learn by doing this game

https://domindez.github.io/mistery/

The problem is that fetch is not working from my phone when I am working in localhost:3000, and it's also not working after I deployed to GitHub pages.

But if I go try from my pc then it works perfectly, in local and on GitHub pages.

This is one of my fetch:

```
  window.onload = function () {

  fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/onload", {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      setCurrentStatus(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this `localhost:3000` an app running on your PC?

Comment: `localhost` addresses the local device. You're running a backend on your PC, but not on your smartphone.

Comment: If so, then you need to deploy your app running on your PC somewhere, have a proper publicly accessed URL then use that URL in code deployed to Github pages

Answer (score 0):

Whatever server you want `http://localhost:3000/api/onload` to react is running on your PC.

[`localhost` is the private loopback address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) hostname. It means "This computer".

It works when you access the page from your PC because it is running on your PC.

`localhost` for your phone is your phone, where you aren't running the server.

---

You need to run the server somewhere accessible from every device you want to access it (be that your LAN or the public Internet) and change the hostname to an IP address on that network.

Comment: But I deployed the backend also to github pages, how can I redirect the fetch to the correct addres?

Comment: You can't deploy the backend to github pages, it only supports static files. (If you *could* then you would need to change the hostname and port number to where you deployed it to or use an relative URL instead of an absolute one).